# Things to take care while sending the username and password using Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Normally we have login page with username, password filed and signin button. Using the normal form based approach we send the data on and page gets post back. Now i would like to change this using the Ajax.

As Ajax too using the normal HTTP so i guess nothing in different from the existing workflow barring postback right ?

Now my question is is what all securities issues can be there? and what care should be taken for doing so ? 
Should we encode data using say base64 or so before sending using Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use https that way your password is secure.